# trying to increment the list value if key exits

Tags: python, dictionary

```
for line in open('transactions.dat','r'):
    item=line.rstrip('\n').split(',')
    custid=item[2]
    amt=item[4]
    if custid in cust:
        amt1=int(cust[custid])+int(amt)
        cust[custid]=amt1
    else:
        cust[custid]=[amt]
```

well i am trying to check if customer id already is there in dictionary then simply add the previous amount and new amount in that customer. Otherwise add that amount in a new position in list. But i am getting error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#74>", line 7, in <module>
amt1=int(cust[custid])+int(amt)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
```

some transaction data is like:

```
101300101,2016-09-03,376248582,1013,10.92

109400132,2016-09-03,391031719,1094,36.72

136100107,2016-09-03,391031719,1361,28.77
```

Comment: Replace `cust[custid]=[amt]` with `cust[custid]=amt`?

Comment: no it doesnot work. Problem is in line 7 of my code

Comment: The error in line 7 is the *consequence* of the bug that Isamael pointed at.

Comment: no it doesnot work. it gives this error :     amt1=int(cust[custid])+int(amt)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'

Comment: @Kam, it gives you this error **even when** you made the change I suggested?

Comment: yes cust[custid]=amt i changed in else statement.... but it keeps error in      amt1=int(cust[custid])+int(amt)

Comment: where and how do you define `cust` ?

Comment: cust is a dictionary defined at top.... cust={}

Comment: @Kam yes, but the error changes to reveal what is really wrong: `10.92` cannot be `int()`'d

Comment: @TemporalWolf is right. You cannot cast string '10.92' to integer. But you can do this `int(float(amt))`

Comment: Try changing that line 7 into `amt1=int(cust[custid][0])+int(amt)` and change line 8 into `cust[custid]=[amt1]` if you don't want to change your dictionary.

Comment: it still gives error. invalid literal for int() with base 10: '85.91'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try using `defaultdict`? It would make your job much easier.

```
from collections import defaultdict

cust = defaultdict(int)
for line in open('transactions.dat','r'):
    item=line.rstrip('\n').split(',')
    custid=item[2]
    amt=item[4]

    cust[custid] += float(amt)
```

and why do you try to cast `amt` to int? Looks like it's not an integer in the sample lines you posted. If you really want to use integer change `float(amt)` to `int(float(amt))`.

Comment: wat i am trying to do is tat add similar amounts for the same customer id and then add in list... instead of having multiple references to customer id

Comment: What you are trying to do is not clear to me. Are you trying to make list of all `amounts` for each client or find the sum of all amounts for each client?

Comment: trying to add the amounts for customers with same id. so that each customer can view the total

Comment: Then my answer should work. It creates a new custid in the dictionary if custid doesn't exit, otherwise it will find and add `amt` to the customer record. Why do you think it doesn't work?

Comment: it works i have tried just there was an issue in some other part