# adding string objects which are numbers in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

```
for line in open('transactions.dat','r'):
item=line.rstrip('\n')
item=item.split(',')
custid=item[2]
amt=item[4]
if custid in cust1:
    a=cust1[custid]
    b=amt
    c=(a)+(b)
    print(cust1[custid]+" : "+a+" :"+b+":"+c)
    break
else:
    cust1[custid]=amt
```

> ```
> Output:       
> 85.91 : 85.91 :85.91:85.9185.91
> ```

Well above is my code what I want is

- when I read from a file I want to add the customer amount with same
  id.
- Secondly there should not be repetition of customer id in my
  dictionary.

  so I am trying to add customer amount which is `c` but it gives me appended string instead of adding the two. You can see in the last part of my output which is value of `c`. So how do I add the values.

Sample transaction data:

```
109400182,2016-09-10,119257029,1094,40.29

109400183,2016-09-10,119257029,1094,9.99

377700146,2016-09-10,119257029,3777,49.37

276900142,2016-09-10,135127654,2769,23.31

276900143,2016-09-10,135127654,2769,25.58
```

Comment: This wont even compile, as `cust1` is not defined before it is used.

Comment: well i have defined in my code above. cust1={}

Comment: What you read from a file will naturally be a `str` so you will just end up concatenating the values. You need to cast it to `int()` or, more likely, `float()`. Which makes me wonder what was wrong with the answer provided in your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40369226/trying-to-increment-the-list-value-if-key-exits)

Comment: it gives me this error:    print(cust1[custid]+" : "+a+" :"+b+":"+c)
TypeError: Can't convert 'float' object to str implicitly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You reading strings, instead of floats, from the file. Use this `amt=float(item[4])` to convert strings representing numbers to floats, and then `print(str(cust1[custid])+" : "+str(a)+" :"+str(b)+":"+str(c))` to print out.

Comment: I think using a `" {} : {} : {} : {} ".format(cust1[custid],a,b,c)` or something equivalent may be more readable.

Comment: @jadsq that's true. But I tend to not change too much of the orginal program. Otherwise, you could rewrite it all for better solution.

Comment: @roganjosh No need. If amt is already `float`, everything else will be float as well.

Comment: @roganjosh my anwser writes: `amt=float(item[4])`. This changes strings to float.

Comment: Aha, my apologies. Missed the knock-on effect on `b` and the stored result in dict.

Comment: thanks it works now. issue was with having str() in print

Answer (score 0):

Your code may need lots of refactor, but in a nutshell and if I understand what you are trying to do you could do

```
c = float(a) + float(b)
```

and that should work.